# Predefined Haskell operator for applying pure values in an Applicative?

Tags: haskell, operators, applicative

If I have a function (e.g. of type `a -> b`) wrapped in an `Applicative` and a value that can be applied to it (i.e. a value of type `a` in the above example), I can apply it as follows:

```
doSomething :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
doSomething wrappedFn arg = wrappedFn <*> (pure arg)
```

I find myself doing this a lot.  Is there a standard, predefined operator somewhere that will make this code more concise, or do I need to define one myself?  If the latter, is there a conventional name for it?

Comment: [This?](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Applicative+f+%3D%3E+f+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+f+b)

Comment: Note that `doSomething` isn't saving you very much typing. It just replaces the calls to `<*>` and `pure` with a call to `doSomething`. And importantly, it doesn't scale to 2+ argument functions, especially if you want to allow some of the arguments to be pure and some to be wrapped. I think it's better for readability to just write `f <*> pure x` and `f <*> x <*> pure y`.

Comment: @Alec - yes, that seems to be what I'm looking for.  Wonder why hoogle didn't find it...

Comment: @amolloy - `doSomething` is intended as an example of what I'm doing in an application-specific context, rather than a general purpose function I'm trying to define.  More specifically, what I'm trying to do right now is define a combinator function that works on a family of data constructors that all have the same first argument type, which automatically supplies the appropriate value to that argument, returning the result in a monad (because the value to supply to that argument is supplied by a monad).

Comment: @Jules The question in your OP and the question in your comment are entirely different questions. More importantly, the latter question is far too vague to get a useful answer here. You should state what you want to accomplish more concretely.

Comment: @user2407038 - what I want is an operator that is equivalent to `a <*> (pure b)`; the code in my question is an example of the kind of code I would be using this operator in.  Obviously I can define this myself, but if there is a standard way of doing this I would like to use that instead.

Comment: @Jules The standard way of writing `a <*> pure b` is `a <*> pure b`. This is because `a` and `b` are abstract, unspecified things - you have only told us that `a :: F x` for some `Applicative F`. There is no such general operator for `Applicative`, because there are an absurd number of such general operators for `Applicative`, because `Applicative` itself is so general. If you state what you want to achieve more concretely, then your question may actually have an answer.

Comment: @user2407038 - my aim is simply to simplify the use of code that returns a data constructor wrapped in a monad, as described in the comment above.  Basically, I have a lot of code in my application that, if I don't define such an operator, is going to result in literally hundreds of "pure" invocations that are essentially noise.  I want to remove them, as I described in the question.  As mentioned in above comments, `a` is a data constructor wrapped in a monad, and `b` is an argument to that constructor (of unspecified type because it could be any of a number of types).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a standard, predefined operator somewhere that will make this code more concise…?

No.

> … or do I need to define one myself?

Yes (unless you want to import external packages).

> If the latter, is there a conventional name for it?

It's called [`(??)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-) in lens, and some have [other names](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Functor%20f%20%3D%3E%20f%20%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20f%20b). According to lens, it's a generalized variant of `flip`, which makes sense:

```
flip ::             (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
(??) :: Functor f => f   (b -> c) -> b -> f c
```

Substitute `f` with `((->) a` and you get `flip` from `(??)`. Therefore, you can call it *generalized flip*.

By the way, you don't need `Applicative`. `Functor` is enough:

```
gFlip :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
gFlip f x = fmap ($x) f
```

Some examples:

```
ghci> gFlip [(+ 1),(* 2)] 2
[3, 4]
ghci> gFlip (++) "world" "hello"
"helloworld"
```

Answer (score 3):

There actually is a moderately well-known version of this operator, namely, [`(??)` from *lens*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-):

```
(??) :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
```

Note the `Functor` constraint. It turns out that `Applicative` isn't necessary, as it can be defined as `\f x -> ($ x) <$> f`.

The canonical use case for `(??)` is with the function functor, as an infix `flip`:

```
GHCi> execState ?? [] $ modify (1:)
[1]
```

In the general case, it does exactly what you want:

```
GHCi> [negate] ?? 3
[-3]
```

(Personally, I still find `[negate] <*> pure 3` more readable, but YMMV.)

Comment: @Zeta I probably should renew my stock of trivial examples :D